# Weird java.lang.NoSuchFieldError in webapp of tomcat build with maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

my web project is building with maven, and deploy to tomcat7.

I use a maven multiple modules to organize my project.

It's ok to package a war file and copy to tomcat webapp directory.

But the weird thing came up, when I try a visit my enum field, it throws a java.lang.NoSuchFieldError exception.

I'm very sure I hava this field, and even decompile the .class file from jar in the tomcat webapp lib directory.The field is absolutely right there!

I'm so confused.

Any suggestion is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: *"I'm very sure I hava this field, and even decompile the .class file from jar in the tomcat webapp lib directory."* -  Have you checked that there is not another version of the ".class" file in a different JAR file, either in your WAR, or deployed separately as a shared library?

Comment: Thank you for you advise.I have checked my project carefully.My package name + class name is unique.In fact, this weird class is a enum.

I check my git log, all my old enum fileds is ok, my new enum fields is all cannot be access(java.lang.NoSuchFieldError).

As if the class is never updated any more.

Comment: That's not what I suggested.  I suggested that you check for **multiple copies** of the class in JARs in the Tomcat tree (including your deployed webapp).  This is some problem in your build and/or deployment methodology.

Comment: Really appreciate for your suggestion inspiring me.

I added a logging statement of `logger.debug("",FieldLostEnum.class.getResource(""));` before the statement throws NoSuchFieldError.

It turns out this class is loaded from a maven repository jar file which I had deleted from my project but still stays in maven repository files.And one of my modules refer to it.

Thank you again! You are my hero!

Comment: can you update with your basic setup here jsp, controllers etc